# Why timestamp of different days are same without part of time?

Tags: java, timestamp

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        long DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date yDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("2020-06-12 23:58:33");
        System.out.println(yDate.getTime() - (yDate.getTime() % DAY));

        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("2020-06-13 00:29:38");
        System.out.println(date.getTime() - date.getTime() % DAY);
    }
```

the console print:
1591920000000
1591920000000

Comment: Hey! You need to consider timezones.

Comment: @akuzminykh Doesn't this *consider* the timezone of the system `Locale`?

Comment: @deHaar I mean they could be two different days in the OPs timezone but the same day in UTC.

Comment: @akuzminykh yes, I know... Just wanted to point out that timezones are considered by this code (but maybe not by the coder).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Also don’t do your own time math, it’s more complicated than most people think. Leave finding the start of the day to proven library methods.

Comment: Thanks for help, take a few days  finally i realize what's wrong with my code, lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of solving your problem with `java.time` instead of the outdated classes from `java.util`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // define an up-to-date(-time) formatter and specify the output language
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                                    Locale.ENGLISH);
    // define two timezones to be used later
    ZoneId shanghai = ZoneId.of("Asia/Shanghai");
    ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC");

    /*
     * Parse the datetimes to a ZonedDateTime each, because timezones matter here...
     * This uses two different ones in order to highlight how timezones matter here
     */
    ZonedDateTime zdtShanghaiOne = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-06-12 23:58:33", dtf)
                                                    .atZone(shanghai);
    ZonedDateTime zdtShanghaiTwo = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-06-13 00:29:38", dtf)
                                                    .atZone(shanghai);
    ZonedDateTime zdtUtcOne = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-06-12 23:58:33", dtf)
                                                    .atZone(utc);
    ZonedDateTime zdtUtcTwo = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-06-13 00:29:38", dtf)
                                                    .atZone(utc);
    /*
     * Print the millis as a result of subtracting the time information.
     * Acutally, this way to get a datetime of the form "yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00.0'Zone'"
     * takes the datetime and returns the same date with a time of 0 hours, minutes, seconds...
     */
    System.out.println("Shanghai millis day one:\t"
                + zdtShanghaiOne.with(LocalTime.MIN).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
    System.out.println("Shanghai millis day two:\t"
                + zdtShanghaiTwo.with(LocalTime.MIN).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
    System.out.println("UTC millis day one:\t\t"
                + zdtUtcOne.with(LocalTime.MIN).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
    System.out.println("UTC millis day two:\t\t"
                + zdtUtcTwo.with(LocalTime.MIN).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
}
```

This leads to an output of

```
Shanghai millis day one:    1591891200000
Shanghai millis day two:    1591977600000
UTC millis day one:         1591920000000
UTC millis day two:         1592006400000
```

It's really recommended to use `java.time` to not have to rely on own calculations that may fail because of missing timezone information (to code and / or coder).

Answer (score 0):

It is because of time zone. Those dates are not on a `DAY` boundary because of time zone, try

```
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
        Date yDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("2020-06-12 23:58:33 +0000");
        System.out.println(yDate.getTime() - (yDate.getTime() % DAY));

        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("2020-06-13 00:29:38 +0000");
        System.out.println(date.getTime() - (date.getTime() % DAY));
```

Comment: Note this shifts the days to GMT which is on the DAY boundary. Alternative, which is probably what you are looking for, is to adjust the time values with the difference between your time zone and GMT and then mod that.